# asp.net Gridview sum multiple column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to sum columns dynamically and add as label.

I have gridview called "GrdDynamic"

**GrdDynamic_RowDataBound**

```
protected void GrdDynamic_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
int total = 0;

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdDynamic.Rows)
{
   for (int i = 6; i <= GrdDynamic.Columns.Count; i++)
   {

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[i].Text))
       {
        total = total + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[i].Text);
       }


      Label label = new Label();
      e.Row.Cells[i].Text = total.ToString();
      label.Text = "total" + " " + total;
      e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(label);

   }
}
}
}
```

I need to sum according to every column dynamically after 6. column .

**As instance:**

If i have 10 columns

i must sum from 6. column to 10. column as below

```
6. column sum is 500

7. column sum is 350

8. column sum is 150

9. column sum is 100

10.column sum is 330
```

How can i do this in code side

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is it's aspx, what is it's datasource? Also, what's wrong with your current approach apart from the fact that you start with the 7th column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
i <= GridView1.Columns.Count;
```

Should be:

```
i < GridView1.Columns.Count;
```

Or you'll be accessing a column that doesn't exist.